# Generate and save a custom cookie on the serverside

Tags: php, cookies, curl, libcurl, httpcookie

I would like to generate a cookie (on the server side so there won't be any browser) with specific name/values and save it in a text file (e.g with fopen ). Later I'm planning to to use that cookie with cURL . The problem is that I don't understand what's the cookie format and how should I save it . When I look on the cookies saved by cURL I have something like this

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://www.netscape.com/newsref/std/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

www.example.com   FALSE   /       FALSE   0       ASP.NET_SessionId       3ddldk5iccxrj45fsl2ctrd
www.example.com   FALSE   /       FALSE   32522347      sccouscIX       548913113
```

I don't understand the spaces and what method I should use to generate a working cookie . As proof of concept I would like to generate a simple cookie with name : exampleId and value 000000000

```
exampleId   000000000   /   www.example.org
```

**Update just to make sure the question is understood:  I need to generate a custom cookie not to get one with cURL generated by other websites.**
  I also found the [Original Netscape cookie specification](http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html) on curl website

Comment: To be clear, could this cookie potentially be used by specific website visitors or by any website visitor that the server is in contact with? The reason for the question is you may have to work out how to assign the right cookie to the right site visitor to ensure you're not sharing the wrong information with the wrong visitor, if it is being used this way, e.g. 1 file per visitor for cookie storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://xiix.wordpress.com/2006/03/23/mozillafirefox-cookie-format/

Answer (score 0):

I think that http://coderscult.com/php/php-curl/2008/05/20/php-curl-cookies-example/ has the code to demo exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: As I already responded to sam and updated the question to make it clear I don't need to get the cookies with cURL . In the example you gave me the cURL script visits a page and saves the cookie provided by that page/site. However  I need to generate a cookie manually (with the values that I need) but unfortunately I didn't find/understood yet what's the cookie standard .

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to interpret the cookie file manually. Curl can set the cookie, store it in a place you specify, and the load data from it. I presume you are doing this in php. The php.net site is pretty well document on this.
Here is what i did
HTTP LIVE headers a plugin for firefox
When you call the url(say the login url) this plugin will tell you all that you need to post.
When you call the url with these post values (set in curl_set_opt), curl will store the relevant data in the cookie file you specify.
In your subsequent call you tell curl to load this cookie.

Comment: @sam I know that cURL generates the cookie automatically if you set the options but I want to generate a custom cookie not to get one genereated by other websites.

Comment: By custom cookie you mean custom data in the cookie or ?

Comment: @sam exactly that what I asked for . in my question I asked for a simple proof of concept (e.g exampleId   000000000   /   www.example.org )

Comment: @sam I know about setcookie(); but how do I save it in the right format ?

Comment: I had a project recently where i wanted to a script to login and fetch data from a webpage. I tried modifying the data in the cookie manually, but it did'nt work. As you mentioned the spaces and other characters must mean something for the cookie to be interpreted properly. The cookie had to be set by curl for it to work.

Comment: @sam I have the same issue .. that's the question about! 'cookie standard'

Comment: you may want to check this article ! http://xiix.wordpress.com/2006/03/23/mozillafirefox-cookie-format/